# bootstrap-table hide column in mobile view

Tags: bootstrap-table

I have a checkbox column which should only be visible on desktop and not on Mobile or Tabs.

There are no options available in the documentation to hide/show any columns based on the devise.

Can we do this?

Answer (score 36):

This is now (4.2) done as explained here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

For table cells you have to use e.g.

```
<th class="d-none d-lg-table-cell">
```

This will display the table cell only on large displays an upwards.

Comment: helpful answer! bs5 link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements and just a quick reminder that you must apply this class to the <td> elements as well

Answer (score 19):

You can use the following

```
hidden-sm : Hidden on small devices ( Tablets ( >= 768 px))
hidden-xs: Hidden on extra small devices ( Phones ( <768 px))
```

example

```
<th class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Your Column</th>

<td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Value </td>
```

Comment: Not sure about the OP but this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: This is for Bootstrap 3.x, see other replies for 4.x approach

Answer (score 14):

After Bootstrap `v4.0+` a good approach is

```
<th scope="col" class="d-none d-sm-table-cell">Column</th>
```

`d-none` hides the element on XS (mobile) viewports and `d-sm-table-cell` keeps it visible SM onwards (tablets and bigger)

Comment: Yeah! I was messing up my table putting ```d-sm-block``` instead of ```d-sm-table-cell```

Answer (score 8):

I might be late to this but I been using bootstrap's .d classes for mobile-friendly development to hide/show few things, hope this helps!
[BootStrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#display-in-print)

[image]

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/pushpakDev/pen/pojPdGY) example for table

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<h2>Good Table</h2>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="display:none">Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none">Data 1.1</td>
            <td>Data 1.2</td>
            <td>Data 1.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none">Data 2.1</td>
            <td>Data 2.2</td>
            <td>Data 2.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none">Data 3.1</td>
            <td>Data 3.2</td>
            <td>Data 3.3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<h2>Bad Table</h2>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="display:none">Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none">Data 1.1</td>
            <td>Data 1.2</td>
            <td>Data 1.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 2.1</td>
            <td>Data 2.2</td>
            <td>Data 2.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none">Data 3.1</td>
            <td>Data 3.2</td>
            <td>Data 3.3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `hideColumn()` method to hide the column you want and triggering it via JavaScript or JQuery when the viewport goes to mobile.

Here's a related issue example of your question:
https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/issues/220.html

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 4 use the `.d-*` [classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements).
E.g. `<th class="d-block d-sm-none" ..>` to only display a column on a small device.

This example https://live.bootstrap-table.com/code/marceloverdijk/3269 shows a country column and and for sm(all) devices it shows the 2 char code like `US` and for non small devices it shows `United States`.

Comment: This is general way of hiding elemets, but table column should NOT be displayed as block, otherwise it won't allign, instead it will cover all available area (as block div element)

Answer (score 0):

From Bootstrap documentation for Display Property: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/display/

hide on sm and wider screens
hide on screens smaller than sm

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33756530)

Answer (score -1):

I think `visible` and `cardVisible` options can help you: http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#column-options.

Comment: This won't help as `data-visible` has only a `true` or `false` option; nothing responsive / device related.